# How to Set the focus on multitab window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent child window. when i close the child window i have to set the focus on that parent window.it is a multitab window.Does anyone know how to set the focus on multitab window. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code in your `child window`,

```
window.onunload = function(){
   $('#tab-1', window.parent.document).addClass('active');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in child window

> window.onbeforeunload = function() {
>
> > window.opener.focus();
>
> }